# Dimensions of forms and vectors in Lie and interior derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

I read D. Bachman's as well as parts of H. M. Edwards' textbook on forms. Now trying to understand Lie and interior derivatives.

Suppose $\omega$ is 1-form defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$. What is $\omega(X)$? From what I understand,

$$\omega = \sum_{i = 1} ^n \omega_i dx_i$$

$\omega(X) = \omega X$, they are multiplied when $X$ is a scalar expression ($X = \sum_{i  = 1} ^n X_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$)

$\omega(X) = \omega \cdot X = \sum_{i=1} ^n \omega_i X_i$, when $X$ is a 2-vector, 3-vector,...

Is this correct?

What is $\omega(X)=?$ when $\omega$ is a 2-form? A 3-form?

In your answer, if possible please avoid much diff. geom. notation; and possibly use calculus/ vectors concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object $\omega(X)$ does NOT represent multiplication.  The idea of a differential form is actually built off ideas from linear algebra and then turned into calculus-based concepts when dealing with manifolds.

Given a vector space $V$, there is a "companion" space we can define here called the **dual space** and usually denoted by $V^*$.  What the dual space consists of are *linear functionals* which are linear mappings $f:V \to \mathbb{R}$.

Coming back to the idea of a differential form, a $1$-form is a type of smoothly-varying linear functional that takes in a vector field $X$ and outputs a single number at each point.  For instance, $\omega$ is a smooth $1$-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ then at each point of $\mathbb{R}^3$ $\omega$ can take a vector as input and outputs a number.  The composite $\omega(X)$ is now basically a function $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$.  The way this is usually written is that $1$-forms in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are usually written as $dx^1, dx^2, dx^3$ and the corresponding tangent vectors in those directions are $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^3}$ where we typically have
$$
dx^i\left (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right ) \;\; =\;\; \delta_j^i.
$$

It's not proper to think of this strictly of multiplication, and the reason for this is that thinking of this as multiplication doesn't extend well into higher dimensions.  Extending this to other forms, a $2$-form is basically a linear functional that takes in two vectors and outputs a number, so if $\eta$ is a $2$-form it will take in two vectors $X$ and $Y$ and output a number $\eta(X,Y)$.  A $k$-form will take in $k$-many vectors $\eta(X_1,\ldots, X_k)$.  $2$-forms in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are going to look like $dx^1\wedge dx^2, dx^2\wedge dx^3, dx^3\wedge dx^1$ where the operation on vectors is given by

$$
dx^i\wedge dx^j(X,Y) \;\; =\;\; dx^i(X)dx^j(Y) - dx^i(Y)dx^j(X).
$$

**General Principles for Computing Lie Derivatives**

Qualitatively, the Lie derivative of a form is essentially a measure of how much the form is changing as we move it along a curve in a specific tangent direction $X$.  Viewing the vector field $X$ as a differential operator, the Lie derivative of a smooth function (i.e. a $0$-form) is given by 
$$
\mathscr{L}_Xf \;\; =\;\; Xf
$$

where $X$ is acting by differentiation.  For a 1-form $\omega$, we have that 
$$
\mathscr{L}_X\omega(Y) \;\; =\;\; X\omega(Y) - \omega([X,Y])
$$

where $X$ acts on the smooth function $\omega(Y)$ by differentiation, and the vector $[X,Y] = XY - YX$.  The Lie derivative can also be found via **Cartan's Magic Formula** given by
$$
\mathscr{L}_X\omega \;\; =\;\; d(X\lrcorner \omega) + X\lrcorner d\omega
$$

where $d$ represents the exterior derivative and takes $k$-forms to $(k+1)$-forms.

Comment: Thank you; Lin algebra and some diff. geom will be fine; I'm looking more to understanding how to perform computations of Lie and interior derivatives; as well as understanding their meaning. But not as much into knowing the derivation, notations etc of advanced diff. geom. Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: How do we work with the expression $\omega(X)$ when $X$ is a scalar, 3-vector etc

Comment: First, $X$ will almost always be a vector/vector field.  Forms are defined by taking vectors as inputs.  If $\omega$ is a $1$-form then the quantity $\omega(X)$ is actually a smooth real-valued function on the underlying space.  When you have interior multiplication $X \lrcorner \eta$ when $\eta$ is a $k$-form, this actually reduces the type of form it is.  $X \lrcorner\eta$ is a $(k-1)$-form, and the way you compute with each of these is by defining them axiomatically from $1$-forms.

Comment: Yes, this is what I seem to notice too... The computation of the p-form $\eta(X)$ in the end is reduced to computation of 1-forms $\omega(X)$ through determinants. But the question is still open about $X$ itself. It is not the same when $X=\partial_a$ compared to when $X$ is a 3-vector $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$

Comment: It is customary in a calculus setting to write vectors strictly in terms of their components, i.e. $X = (X_1, X_2, X_3)$, but the notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ actually indicate unit basis vectors in the space.  In other words, it is entirely appropriate to write $X = X^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} + X^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2} + X^3\frac{\partial}{\partial x^3}$.  This is done in differential geometry because when we study manifolds there is no single coordinate system which works in a neighborhood.  We therefore define the tangent vectors based on the parameterization.

Comment: Compare $\iota_{a\frac{\partial}{\partial x}} \omega$  to $\iota_{\vec{A}} \omega$. The first case requires computation $\omega(a\frac{\partial}{\partial x})$; the other requires $\omega(\vec{A})$. How do we express these two?

Comment: It honestly all depends on the coordinate representation.  If $\omega$ is a $1$-form then $\iota_{a\partial_x}\omega = \omega(a\partial_x) = a\cdot \omega(\partial_x)$.  If you have a coordinate representation $\vec{A} = a^i\partial_i$ where I'm using summation notation, you will have $\iota_{\vec{A}}\omega = \omega(\vec{A}) = a^i\omega(\partial_i)$ where summation notation is still implied.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not sure at this point where your confusion lies.  I know your title made mention of understanding Lie and interior derivatives, but the prompt of your question makes it seem like you're still understanding what differential forms are.  Even if $\vec{A}$ is a smoothly varying vector field, the computations I gave you are the same.  Forms are alternating multi-linear mappings, they are not themselves derivatives.

Comment: I augmented my post a bit to include some information on the different types of derivatives available to you.  But this is the last I can contribute to this post.  If you still have trouble understanding, keep studying and good luck!

Comment: I'm new to forms :) From all of above, it seems the distinction is 
$dx^i(\partial_j) = \delta^i _j$, and $dx^i(\vec{A}) = A_i$. ...correct?

Comment: Yes, correct.  The $\partial_i$ are basis vectors, and $dx^i$ is what's called the "dual basis" which has this property.  Instead if you have an arbitrary vector $\vec{A}$ then $dx^i$ simply picks off the $\partial_i$-component of $\vec{A}$.

Comment: Reading this thread I can't help thinking that you would be very well-served to learn the basic differential geometry surrounding these ideas. You confusion seems to be that you don't have at your disposal the machinery you need to do this right. I found [this book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441973993) extremely useful I started self-studying these topics.

Comment: I'll also add this [book](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Smooth-Manifolds-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/1441999817/ref=sr_1_2?crid=WG5HCS94BFHM&keywords=introduction+to+smooth+manifolds+john+lee&qid=1574212340&sprefix=john+lee+smoot%2Caps%2C190&sr=8-2) to the list too.